# where is the chrome dev tools "continuous page repainting" option?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

There used to be an option in dev tools under Render right next to the FPS Meter that said "Enable continuous page repainting". Now it's not there. Where did it go?

Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image: no continuous rendering option]

[image: chrome canary]

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/rendering-settings

Comment: @Amogh it is not there...

Comment: I am having it as stated, same version 32 bit

Comment: @Amogh added screenshot, it's not there, the doc also shows an older version of chrome

Comment: I generally use [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html) for this purpose. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/02/Profiling-Long-Paint-Times-with-DevTools-Continuous-Painting-Mode

Comment: @Amogh lol it's not there either... check second screen in post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There used to be an option in dev tools under Render right next to the FPS Meter that said "Enable continuous page repainting". Now it's not there. Where did it go?

It's been removed. See [Crbug issue #523040](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=523040).

The broader question here is, what workflow can you use to replace Continuous Painting Mode (CPM)?

CPM was before my time, but it looks like it gave you a realtime estimate of painting cost for the entire page. There's nothing equivalent to that anymore, but Performance recordings can definitely help you gauge how much painting your page is doing. The general idea is to start recording, interact with your page, and then analyze the recording results to see how many paint events occurred, and how much time each one took. See [Get Started With Analyzing Runtime Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/) to get familiar with the Performance panel.

2 Nov 2017 Update

There's a new feature coming to DevTools in Chrome 64 (which is currently in Canary) that's close to CPM called the [Performance Monitor](https://youtu.be/7-XnEMrQnn4?t=6m9s). It shows a realtime view of FPS, Layouts Per Second, and Style Recalculations Per Second.

Comment: that's really disappointing. why remove an easy to use feature? FPS meter + CPM gave instant feedback on performance. Using Performance recordings works the same way now. "Idle frames" are shown as ~ 1 fps. Frames with not a lot going on show ~4, ~5fps. This is hugely misleading if you want to make sure small animations and things are playing at 60fps. The FPS meter and performance profiler now show how many frames were rendered instead of how quickly the rendered is painting frames. Perhaps if there's no hope for CPM then the FPS meter needs to reflect what it actually shows.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer see my update about the Perf Monitor. Re: your comment I think that's good feedback, I suggest opening an issue on https://crbug.com and discussing with the team.

Answer (score 2):

The "continuous page repainting" debugging option was removed from Chrome quite a few versions ago.  However, you can still get to paint instrumentation in the Performance tab of the developer tools:

Developer tools -> Performance -> Settings -> Enable advanced paint instrumentation

This will not enable continuous repaint since as far as I can tell Chrome no longer does that, but will allow you to see a profile of how your page actually worked during recording, and can be very useful for tracking down performance problems.  It is integrated with other performance profile data as well.

I personally have found this article: https://blog.algolia.com/performant-web-animations/ to be useful if you're working on animations, but I'm not going to summarize it here since it's quite long and I'm not sure you're specifically looking to improve animation performance anyway.  (No association with the author; just useful info.)